# g++ 6.2 default standard requires custom headers are included last?

Tags: c++, g++, header-files

I'm working on a simple exercise that consists of 3 files; main.cpp, mapgrid.hpp, and mapgrid.cpp; that are as below:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "mapgrid.hpp"

/* main program code */
```

mapgrid.hpp

```
#ifndef MAPGRID_HPP
#define MAPGRID_HPP

#include <vector>

struct Point { /* stuff */ };

class MapGrid { /* stuff */ };

#endif // MAPGRID_HPP
```

mapgrid.cpp

```
#include "mapgrid.hpp"

#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

/* implementation for Point and MapGrid */
```

When I try to compile the files as they are above in g++ 6.2.0 without specifying a standard, I get compile errors saying things like `Point does not name a type` and `no 'bool MapGrid::walkForward(int, bool)' member function delcared in bool MapGrid::walkForward(int, bool)`.

The strange thing is that the program compiles and runs correctly if I switch around the #includes in mapgrid.cpp so that mapgrid.hpp comes last:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

#include "mapgrid.hpp"
```

or if I use the -std=c++14 or -std=c++11 flags. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Most likely the hidden /* stuff */ references something that's defined in those other header files.

Comment: The header file uses a std::vector (and I just realized I never actually use anything from <utility> anymore, so I've taken that out now and will edit the post), but I don't understand why that means it can only be included _after_ <cmath> and <algorithm> in mapgrid.cpp instead of before, or why it only works when I explicitly specify c++14.

Comment: Unless you can produce a [mcve], no other answer will be possible.